# Python fitting sinus cardinal and LMFIT library

Tags: python, physics, lmfit

I have a set of data from a physic experiment (simple-slit experiment) in university and i am trying to fit this data to a model that i build from the lmfit library.
I want a sinus cardinal square, in this form:

I(X)= I0.sinc²(pi.a.X/(lambda.D))

with a : the width of the slit,
lambda : wavelenght of the light
D : distance camera/slit
I0 : original intensity

```
import csv as csv
from math import pi
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from lmfit import *

# create data to be fitted
with open('data_1.csv', 'r') as f:
    values = list(csv.reader(f, delimiter=','))
values = np.array(values[1:], dtype=np.float)

position = values[:, 0]
intensity = values[:, 1]

#define function model
def fct(x, I0, a, D, b):
    return I0 * np.square(np.sinc(pi * a * (x + b) / (0.00000063 * D)))
    #b is for the horizontal shift because my experience
    #was centered on 700 due to the camera

# do fit
vmodel = Model(fct)
vmodel.set_param_hint('I0', min=0., max=300.)
vmodel.set_param_hint('a', value=0.0005, min=0.0, max=1.)
vmodel.set_param_hint('D', value=0.53, min=0.0, max=1.)
vmodel.set_param_hint('b', min=0., max=2000.)
pars = vmodel.make_params()
result = vmodel.fit(intensity, pars, x=position)

# write report
print(result.fit_report())

#after we plot the data, with position on x and intensity on y
```

It returns totally wrong values and an error :

```
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars spercent = 
'({0:.2%})'.format(abs(par.stderr/par.value))

[[Model]]
    Model(fct)
[[Fit Statistics]]
    # function evals   = 7
    # data points      = 1280
    # variables        = 4
    chi-square         = 4058147.794
    reduced chi-square = 3180.367
    Akaike info crit   = 10326.876
    Bayesian info crit = 10347.494
[[Variables]]
    I0:   0          +/- 0        (nan%) (init= 0)
    a:    0.00050000 +/- 0        (0.00%) (init= 0.0005)
    D:    0.50000000 +/- 0        (0.00%) (init= 0.5)
    b:    400        +/- 0        (0.00%) (init= 400)
```

Could you help me please ? I tried lots of type models from this library but nothing work correctly and i really need it. I already solved 2D problems with a np.square, and other reading things, the major problem is the model.
Waiting for answers,
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to provide reasonable starting values for all your parameter values.  As you wrote it, there are no initial values for `I0` or `b`  but conveniently(?) these parameters have bounds set, so that initial values can be inferred (probably poorly) as the lower bound -- I don't know how `b` became 400.  Maybe a typo?

Anyway, I would recommend trying

```
pars = vmodel.make_params(I0=150, b=400)
```

and then try the fit again.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.I changed some things in the program, adding smallers intervalls and settings some parameters to not vary, but it doesn't work, results are always bad. Do you want the code with modifications ?

Comment: well, posting complete code (with data) of a simple working example would probably help.  Another suggestion is to plot the data with the model using your initial parameter values and see if it is even close to a good match to your data.